# How can i see the live parse tree using Antlr4 Ide in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, antlr, grammar, antlr4

I'm new using Antlr4 but I know that exist a plugin for Eclipse.
I have a simple question...After I created the g4 file how can I visualize the live parse tree in order to see the tree of an input expression?
Thanks

Comment: Eclipse IS an IDE. Do you mean to say that there exists a plugin for Eclipse?

Comment: sorry for the bad explanation

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Currently there is no provision for viewing live parse tree in [ANTLR 4 IDE for Eclipse](https://github.com/jknack/antlr4ide).

Meanwhile, you can see the parse tree using -gui switch in the command line. It also provides a feature of saving the parse tree as PNG.

Comment: but if I write something specific in the run configuration of eclipse can I generate the parseTree?
By the way someone can precisely explain me how to generate this parse tree if I have a project in eclipse?
Thanks

Comment: If you are familiar with Ant scripts, just write one script to compile all the generated `.java` files to `.class` files and then invoke the `grun` command on the input. The ANTLR4IDE by Edgar Espina will automatically generate the java files by running the `antlr4` command.

Comment: This answer is simply incorrect (at this date): there *is* provision for viewing live parse trees. See the other answer, which gives exact instructions

Answer (score 26):

After installing Antlr4Ide plugin in Eclipse:

- Window>Show View>Other, Antlr4>Parse tree
- Activate g4 file
- Click parsing rule in g4 file, Parse tree now shows active rule above source editor box

In the parse tree view you see a live source editor on the left, with syntax highlighting for your language. When you enter code in your language there, the tree will update on the right. The antlr console shows parsing errors at the same time.

Comment: In eclipse Oxygen I can't "Click parsing rule in g4 file,".
My situation is described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45870463/antlr-parse-tree-not-showed-in-eclipse?noredirect=1#comment78709638_45870463 .
Can you help me?