# Antlr4 Parse Tree view stays empty

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, antlr4

I am using eclipse luna (4.4) with the Antlr4 plugin with Xtext 2.6.2

I already built a simple grammar to test the grammar and look at a parse tree. Antlr4 does include a parse tree view for that.

I have already seen the answer in this post:
[How can i see the live parse tree using Antlr4 Ide in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23389728/how-can-i-see-the-live-parse-tree-using-antlr4-ide-in-eclipse/28741379#28741379)

The point is that when I do what is described in the answer the right field of the parse tree view stays empty.

```
Example grammar

grammar Example;
start: exp EOF;
exp : exp '+' exp | ID;
ID: [a..z]+;
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found any solution for eclipse.

But what I did was changing to Intellij, where the plugin works fine including the parse tree view.