# Antlr: parse tree not showed in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, parsing, eclipse-plugin, antlr, antlr4

The view `Parse Tree` in Eclipse Oxygen is empty and white.
I can compile my `Hello.g4` grammar, see the `Syntax Diagram` but the `Parse Tree` view is empty.
How can I fix it?
[image]

Comment: Did you actually do a parse run? The parse tree is the result of parsing and hence cannot be shown until you parsed something.

Comment: Acutally, I have only thoose 2 files: Hello.g4 and input.
I go in the arrow near the run button, run configurations.
There, I add a new Java application, called TestRig, with org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig as main class and Hello simbolo_iniziale input as arguments.
To launch it, I go in the arrow near the run button and I press TestRig.
If I write something wrong in the input file, I have errors, otherwise everything seems ok. This is a parse run, isn't it?